# the shipping information was unable to be saved. Verify the input data and try again in Maneto 2.3.2

Tags: shipping, magento2.3.2, input, search-type

we are facing issue
the shipping information was unable to be saved. Verify the input data and try again
when customer is doing the checkout

Magento ver. 2.3.2

Answer (score 0):

**hey try to check  following things one of them could be the issue:-**

**First**

the date format of your calendar might not be  supported by the date format of database, so you have to match them.

**Second**

it is due to the email validation. If you have a domain with a .cloud extension, and use this for email - e.g. test@test.cloud - you will get the same issue. Changing to a test@test.com and the order proceeds as normal.

**Hope this helps.**

Comment: is there any link of this with currency converter extension?

Comment: for this you need to post another question did the above ans works for you?

Comment: its working now after doing the necessary changes in the currency converter